# How to fetch source string from a utf-8 represented string

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a page get from the Internet, and the content is utf-8 encoded as a String which may be like:

```
{"has_more": true, "items": [{"body": "\u6ca1\u6709\u4f20\u8bf4\u4e2d\u7684\u90a3\u4e48\u597d",...}
```

I tried to use URLDecoder.decode(), but it doesn't work, it output exactly what the input is. Any suggestions? This is String object that utf-8 encoded explicit, it's not a inputStream or sth. I have done some searching effort, finding little relevant.

Comment: I think you have to learn about JSON.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code notation is u-encoded (`\uXXXX`) but the String itself is an undistinguishable normal string (Java/JavaScript), like `\n` or `\t`.

The JDK has a conversion tool though:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 -reverse mypage.json plain-utf8.json
```

Comment: @zoujyjs you are not supposed to read it in that form, you are supposed to parse the JSON and read the result.

Comment: @Esailija yeah, thanks for suggestion. I am now using JSONObject to parse the string, I just want to be able to read some sample output when I am testing the web interface. And I think google GSON is not good enough in this application, to translate a string to a Object.

Answer (score 1):

That's JSON encoding, which handles certain specific characters in a specific way. It is not the URL Encoding, hence that not working.

Why don't you try using a JSON library? [json simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) or [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) are good ones to start off.

As a curiosity: here's where the encoding you're seeing is described: [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert them to a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the libs in Java -   [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its [JSON](http://json.org/) (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

Go through  http://www.json.org/java/